# Do you know what this wild perennial is?

Tags: identification, perennials

Do you know what his wild perennial is?

Zone is 8a, central Europe. Photo taken mid-May. Removed from the ground because of fence construction. Is it worth transplanting?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Quite a lot of weeds or wildflowers look like this, but it might be Rosebay  Willowherb, a rather attractive flowering plant that unfortunately produces lots of seed which germinates freely, so not desirable in most gardens. Need to wait for flowers really to be sure

Comment: Does the foliage, when crushed, smell like aniseseed or licorice?

Comment: @Jurp Almost no smell, nothing like licorice etc.

Comment: Thanks, VividD; I was thinking it looked like a New England Aster, which would've been weird given your location. Looks like we have to wait for the flowers, like Bamboo said.

Comment: It seems *Solidago canadensis*, so a very invasive plant. The flowers could be nice, but you should choose your garden or him. But attachment of leaves are more like lettuce.Google and try to remember if you saw something like them.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I am going to keep it in container, far from garden,just in case it is so invasive. But Solidago canadensis. I looked up, has three main veins in its leaves, while this plant doesn't. But certainly thanks for attempt.

Comment: @Jurp The "collars" (the parts close to the stem) of the leaves match between New England Aster and this plant, I checked. New England Aster is not native here, but it is a relatively popular ornamental plant.

Comment: Vivid - I checked my own NE Aster cultivars and they also lack the scent I'm used to  - maybe the scent is a late-season feature of the plant. Please post the flowers when they bloom.

Comment: My immediate thought was the same as the first answer, rose bay willow herb, although it is impossible to identify anything definitely from photos of the leaves.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making my comment an answer - Symphyotrichum novae-angliae (syn. Aster novae-angliae). We really needed to see the flowers on this one, though.

Answer (score 0):

Google images thinks one of your photos looks like 
"large-flowered evening primrose".

Ref: [large-flowered evening primrose](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&safe=active&q=large-flowered%20evening%20primrose&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVh8Kf-orbAhXrKsAKHaEIAAwQvQ4IJigA&dlnr=1&sei=_4T8WpfHEsqUgAbqm5qYDQ)

Comment: Disagree: evening primroses don’t have leaves that wrap around the main stem. And the leaves seem a tad too narrow.